# How can I render a mutable video to a PyQt widget?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, rendering, video-editing

I am working on a video editing application in python using PyQt. I want to be able to make "clips" out of video files and have the ability to concatenate these clips to render a new video. I have used the QMediaPlayer class with a VideoSurface to play back a video that has instantiated a QVideoWidget with a .mp4 file, but I want to play back a video using a numpy array (preferred) or some mutable object. I have looked through some open source video editors (OpenShot, Vidcutter, Pitivi) but I cannot seem to find what I need. Many use C++ frameworks, with which I am unfamiliar.

I have used multithreading and for-loops to try to hack my way through a solution by using a QImage object, meaning I loop through a video frame by frame, extracting the numpy array representation of each frame and converting it a QImage object and calling repaint(). Unfortunately, even with calling this function on a new thread, this does not render at the desired speed. This was inspired by moviepy's method of rendering clips with pygame. I have also looked through PyQt documentation, but these classes do not seem to meet my needs or I do not understand them. Graphical User Interface programming is new to me.

I know that fps is not the issue, and if you run the code below with an updated VideoFileCLip parameter, the video will display (without sound) at approximately 75% of the original frame rate. And, the window will "not respond" if there is no multithreading. I have tried fps of 30 and 60, but still my for-loop method is not desired because other tasks will be performed elsewhere, and the computational complexity will only increase.

Here is a simplified version that will reveal the issue:

```
import numpy as np                                                     
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPainter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
import threading
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

class Demo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.video = VideoFileClip(r'C:\Users\jklew\Videos\Music\Fractalia.MP4') # I am using a real video
        im_np = self.video.get_frame(0)
        self.image = QImage(im_np, im_np.shape[1], im_np.shape[0],                                                                                                                                                 
                        QImage.Format_RGB888)
        self.stopEvent = threading.Event()
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.display_clip, args=())
        self.thread.start()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawImage(self.rect(), self.image)

    def display_clip(self, fps=60):
        clip = self.video
        img = clip.get_frame(0) # returns numpy array of frame at time 0

        t0 = time.time()

        for t in np.arange(1.0 / fps, clip.duration-.001, 1.0 / fps):
            
            img = clip.get_frame(t) # returns numpy array of frame at time t
            # print(img.shape)
            t1 = time.time()
            time.sleep(max(0, t - (t1-t0))) # loop at framerate specified
            self.imdisplay(img) #, screen)
    
    def imdisplay(self, img_array):
        # fill the widget with the image array
        # TODO: Qt widget
        self.image = QImage(img_array, img_array.shape[1], img_array.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
        self.repaint()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = Demo()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This problem also extends to mutable audio data as well.

Comment: Using python for realtime audio/video processing is usually discouraged, as python is certainly not known for its speed. Unless you find a way to do the *whole* processing through external libraries (or you are able to write the core implementation in C++), I won't suggest you to go further, especially since you said that you're new to GUI programming.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it with QPixmaps. Before you show the frames save them into a list:

```
self.frames = []
for file in files:
  pixmap = QPixmap(file)
  self.frames.append(pixmap)
```

and than, when you play the image sequenze back:

```
for frame in self.frames:
            self.<LABELNAME>.setPixmap(frame)
            time.sleep(1/FPS)
```